# How to get RegEx line before instead of after the match?

Tags: regex

I'm using a html script including
(`(^.*${searchterm}.*\n?(.*){1})\n?`, "gm")

gives me the full line of the term + the line below, but I need the line above + the line of the match. How do I get that?

I would search for "car" in a HTML-Script and the get the Line where "xxxxx car xxcyxyx" is found and get the line below that. But I need the Line above that line which matches car.

Comment: please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60412928/edit) and add some examples with expected result. Also, what language/tool are you using?

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://regex101.com/r/orhLAm/1 ?

Comment: Whatever way you use to match the next line, you can probably use to match the previous line, right ? Just put it before. Also, small detail, `{1}` is useless, it means 'match exactly once', which is already the default behavior.

Comment: Probably, but I do not know how to put it before, the Info i do lookup is only in the following line

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PCRE solution:

```
^.+$(?=\R.*?\bcar\b)
```

It matches the line before the line that contains the word "car".

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/pfGhvB/1)